# Thumbs Up vote system

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, query-optimization, vote

I want to create Thumbs Up vote system but I don't know how to do it in best way.

Here's my Entries#vote (controller/action):

```
def vote
    if Entry.where(id: params[:entry_id]).first && Vote.where(entry_id: params[:entry_id], user_id: @current_user.id).first.nil? # Check if entry with given entry_id exist && Check if user vote previously.
        Vote.create(entry_id: params[:entry_id], user_id: @current_user.id) # Create vote
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE `entries` SET `entries`.`points` = `entries`.`points` + 1 WHERE `entries`.`id` = #{params[:entry_id].to_i}") # Update entry points count.
    end

    render nothing: true
end
```

I think it's not optimal way to do it, because this action have lots of query. Here's queries logs:

```
Started GET "/vote/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-20 16:20:01 +0100
Processing by EntriesController#vote as JS
  Parameters: {"entry_id"=>"2"}
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT id, name FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`auth_token` = '6f1aa3b944d530a1d52c6f40bcb69398' LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mEntry Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `entries`.* FROM `entries` WHERE `entries`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mVote Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `votes`.* FROM `votes` WHERE `votes`.`entry_id` = 2 AND `votes`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  BEGIN
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mINSERT INTO `votes` (`entry_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (2, 1)←[0m
  ←[1m←[35m (54.0ms)←[0m  COMMIT
  ←[1m←[36m (16.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mUPDATE `entries` SET `entries`.`points` = `entries`.`points` + 1 WHERE `entries`.`id` = 2←[0m
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 115ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 78.0ms)
```

Anybody have an idea how to do this in best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That controller logic can be cleaned up.  If it's strictly just thumbs up where 1 vote = 1 point, you could use [counter_cache](http://hiteshrawal.blogspot.com/2011/12/rails-counter-cache.html) to track points.  If you also need thumbs down, then you could use [update_counters](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/update_counters) instead.

**Entry.rb**

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes
end
```

**Vote.rb**

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry, :counter_cache => :points  
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes
end
```

**EntriesController#vote**

```
def vote
  Vote.find_or_create_by_entry_id_and_user_id(params[:entry_id], @current_user.id)
  render :nothing
end
```

For new vote SQL log is:

```
  Vote Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "votes".* FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."entry_id" = 3 AND "votes"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "votes" ("created_at", "entry_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 21 Feb 2012 16:51:54 UTC +00:00], ["entry_id", 3], ["updated_at", Tue, 21 Feb 2012 16:51:54 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
  Entry Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" WHERE "entries"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "entries" SET "points" = COALESCE("points", 0) + 1 WHERE "entries"."id" = 3
   (2.3ms)  COMMIT
```

For existing vote:

```
  Vote Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "votes".* FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."entry_id" = 3 AND "votes"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 => #<Vote id: 7, user_id: 1, entry_id: 3, created_at: "2012-02-21 16:51:54", updated_at: "2012-02-21 16:51:54">
```

Comment: Thanks for show me "rails way", but I have 6 queries (without BEGIN and COMMIT) and query which search for entry with given id is sent 2 times (I think counter_cache sent addtional query).
It's still not good :(

PS I checking if entry with given id exist.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your constructors all do their own queries..

you could maybe optimize a bit by doing all the checking and update logic in a database procedure that you call once from the UI... this at least would save you network round trips.

otherwise - look at different ways of construction that maybe are smarter about not loading up the smallest amount of each bit of info...

Comment: If user votes, he can't vote via website by click link, because it's disabled but "bad" user can go via link (example.com/vote/321 for eg.). That's why I must check via query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query to check both an Entry exists and if user hasn't vote on that enrty
Something like this :

```
SELECT enrty.* FROM enrty LEFT JOIN votes ON enrty.voteId=votes.Id AND votes.UserId=userId And enrty.Id=enrtyId WHERE vote.id IS NULL
```

If this query returns an enrty it means that the entry exists and the user have not voted for that enrty yet.

Comment: One query less. It's possible to optimalize it more?
Btw. How to delete COMMIT (it's slow query)?

Comment: I don't think you can make it more optimized since you have to do the insertion and update commands.Commit is part of your transaction and it's necessary to be there because you are working over two different tables and should be a way to rollback the whole process if something goes wrong

Comment: It's possible to send query ONLY when user click button (not via remote link)?

Comment: There's a query that gets the userid and I don't know if it is necessary since you could cache the current user's id.

Comment: I don't get your question . What do you mean by remote link ?

Comment: 1. How to cache user id? |
 2. At this moment AJAX sent request to /votes/:id. And user can sent request via browser. It's possible to do that application accept only request via AJAX not via browser?

Comment: here's an article that show you how to use cache at different level and layers in ruby on rails :http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: we usually cache those objects that we don't write or update them much but we read them often.I don't think that's a good idea to cache votes in memory

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but you can use, or look for inspiration, other gems, such as [vote_fu](https://github.com/objectreload/vote_fu), or [thumbs up](https://github.com/brady8/thumbs_up) (the latter started as a fork of the first one). If you don't end up using one of them, chances are you'll learn something from their code.